# Using nested objects in React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*Objects are not valid as a React child (). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array*

I receive the above error and I don't fully understand the limitations of what it's telling me.
Here is my code that is giving me this error, I have an object where one of the properties has the value of an array of objects:

```
state = {
    clubs: [{
        teamName: something,
        gamesPlayed: [{
            homeTeam: someName,
            awayTeam: someNameElse,
            score: numbers
        },
        {
            homeTeam: ...
            ... etc
        }]
    }]
}
```

The element that renders the code:

```
function RenderTest(props) {
    return (
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <ul style={{paddingLeft: 10+'px'}}>
                        {props.clubs.map( (key, i) => (
                            <li>
                                <div>Team: {key.teamName} ID: {key.teamId}</div> <-- works as expected
                                <div>Games Played: {key.gamesPlayed.home}</div> <-- throws the error
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Does it mean that I cannot have a nested object like this? It seems a bit limiting. It seems logical that I store the data like this - clubs is an array of objects, each one a football team with their games played that season.

Thank you

Comment: is `key.gamesPlayed[i].score` an object ?

Comment: There're no any limitations for data stored in state. Probably some element of `key.gamesPlayed[i].score` is an object

Comment: Surely you do not need the index, each Object has  gamesPlayed.score  . Try it like {key.gamesPlayed.score}

Comment: I have removed the [i], it is now not throwing the error, but still doesn't actually render anything, i do not know why as the value of score is just a sting

Comment: please send in the complete Render code. what is wrapping the `map` ?

Comment: My bad you should use {key.gamesPlaye[0].score} , I didn't catch on gamesPlaye was an array , you just need the first element of it on every iteration

Comment: I recommend do a map over  `gamesPlayed` array too, and use `return` instead of `(`  and check. just a suggestion. also, assign `key` attribute for the first tag in the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
<div>Games Played: {key.gamesPlayed.home}</div>
```

you basically tell react to create a div element with exactly two children:

1. The string 'Games Played: ',
2. Whatever `key.gamesPlayed.home` stores, in this case it is an **array** (Which is basically just an object in javascript)!

React on the other side requires, that children of any components must be either a string or another component. An array is none of that. So in order to make it work, you have to loop over the array and render the respective part of each array element. A short example from my side to replace above code snipped would be

```
<div>
  {key.gamesPlayed.map(game => (
    <div>{game.homeTeam}</div>
  )}
</div>
```

(Assuming `game.homeTeam` is a string!)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but also for the explanation. It is working.
That makes a lot of sense to me now. A lot of nested loops!